# Bind a site to a pinned tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I want certain sites to always open in their respective pinned tab.

Suppose I have a pinned tab, which usually shows questions from superuser.com. When I open a link to superuser.com from a different site in a different tab I want the link to be opened in this pinned tab instead of a new tab.

For example, there could be an extension that adds an option in a pinned tab's context menu to provide a pattern of URL's to always be opened in this tab.

Is there a way to do so?